# Как программно задать обработчик webcal для Firefox?

Tags: java, firefox

Нужно через программу (язык Java) задать обработчик протокола для Firefox. Причем речь идет не о добавлении нового варианта, а именно о задании того варианта, который Firefox будет использоваться без всяких запросов, как будто пользователь указал путь к нужной программе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходим в:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

Переходим в директорию с файлами своего профайла (обычно она там одна) и правим файл "mimeTypes.rdf". Делая все по аналогии с mailto, у меня получилось добавить новый протокол и назначить ему приложение-обработчик.